# moviepy error, "cannot collect memory" or "memory leak" or "memory overflow"

Tags: memory, overflow, collect, moviepy

I encountered this question, but sadly no good answers online, so I want to put the final solutions here.

---

**Here it is:**

You should never give too many videos files(.mp4) to moviepy at once.

---

But you can give it a `parent video`

Then split it to thousands of `subclips` in memory

Actually, in this time, they are not real `clips` (i mean .mp4 file)

---

At this moment, your memory only stored one video, the `parent video`, and the information about `subclips` (where it starts, where it ends)

---

In this way, you feed the clip list to concatenate function, it won't cause memory overflow anymore

---

Here is the demo codes:

```
parent_clip = VideoFileClip("./parent_video.mp4")
clip_list = []
for part in time_parts:
    time_start = part[0]
    time_end = part[1]
    clip_list.append(
        parent_clip.subclip(time_start, time_end)
    )
concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clip_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux(Ubuntu),

you can set a swap partition as a temporary memory.

It solves all kinds of memory leaking problem.

https://www.fosslinux.com/1064/how-to-create-or-add-a-swap-partition-in-ubuntu-and-linux-mint.htm/